# OAuth 2.0: "gmail.send" scope failed to authenticate smtp.gmail.com server

Tags: oauth2-playground

I have tried to authenticate smtp.gmail.com server using OAuth 2.0 Authentication mechanism. When I select scope as "https://mail.gmail.com",I was able to successfully authenticate and send a mail. But my email client is just for sending a mail, so I tried to use the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send", but it resulted in the below error,

< 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiJpbnZhbGlkX3JlcXVlc3QiLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbWFpbC5nb29nbGUuY29tLyJ9

> AQ==
> < 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

We used OAuth 2.0 playground to get the access token.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: I feel your pain. Google should support smtp connections using gmail.send, but for some reason they don't.  I'm not sure if it's a bug or if there is a reason for it.